# Connect to GP Services via GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-api-client

I'm trying to connect to google play services. I have my app released as alpha testing, I have created service for that app, and my mail is in list of testers. When I press sign in button. This what happens on the screen:

[image]

[image]

And then error message: 
Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again.

In code:

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed(): attempting to resolve");
        if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed(): already resolving");
            return;
        }

        if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
            mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;
            if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this, googleApiClient, connectionResult,
                    RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
                mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                googleApiClient.connect();
            } else {
                BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this, requestCode, resultCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
            }
        }
    }
```

In activityResult the result code is 10002 which is SIGN_IN_FAILED not RESULT_OK so it never gets to `googleApiClient.connect();`

And I would like to know why am I getting this result code ... I have created game service, I have authorized the app and i have set app id like :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

I also have permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

But I don't have app released in alpha testing, I haven't uploaded APK, because in game services tab it is written that app is ready for testing. So do I have to realease app as alpha testing in order to test game services? Thanks.

Comment: What does logcat say? It should have a more detailed error message.

Comment: There's no error message because it is handled. On activity result is checked if resultCode is RESULT_OK and if not message: Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again.